# Removing the broadcasting icon when player is in fullscreen on MediaElement

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, mediaelement, windows-media-player

I am using the default MediaElement with AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" and I am trying to remove the CastButton element when the app is in full screen.

I have already created a copy of MediaTransportControls and commented out the CastButton but this doesn't work when in fullscreen any ideas?

Here is the sample project attached:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/83wt4adr8db7xqu/App1.zip?dl=0

My code :

```
  <Style TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
bla bla
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
bla
  <!--<AppBarButton x:Name='CastButton'
           Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
           Visibility="Collapsed"
           MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='7'>
                     <AppBarButton.Icon>
                           <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEC15;"/>
          </AppBarButton>-->
```

bla
    
    bla

My MediaElement:

```
     <MediaElement Source="http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/samples/videos/bigbuck.mp4"
                          AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                          ></MediaElement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost done correctly. The main reason that your `xaml` wasn't merged in global dictionary your application. Just move you `xaml` code:

1. To `App.xaml`
2. Or create some file, which will be contains you style and merge this xaml style with resource dictionary in `App.xaml`

You can see it by code bellow:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/MediaElementStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I did it through second way. [Your project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv8h4zx6ehj61vr/App1.zip?dl=0)